# Изменение фотографии в сообщении по нажатию inline кнопки Aiogram

Tags: python, парсер, telegram-bot, циклы, aiogram

Только начал плотно заниматься языком программирования Python и решил попробовать создать бота, но  очутился перед проблемой, которую не могу решить. Пробовал через цикл for перебирать, но выходит как-то плохо, по нажатию все фотографии быстро меняются до последней из списка.

**Бот парсит данные с сайта и записывает все в список. Мне нужно что бы при каждом нажатии кнопки "next" выводилась следующая фотография из вышеупомянутого списка.**

```py
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton, InputMedia


poster = ['any url photo', 'any url photo', 'any url photo']


next_btn = InlineKeyboardButton(text='next', callback_data='next')

neBTN = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
neBTN.add(next_btn)


@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def photo(message: types.Message):
    file_path = poster[1]
    reply_markup = neBTN

    await bot.send_photo(
        message.chat.id,
        photo=file_path,
        reply_markup=reply_markup,
        caption="Test caption!",
    )


@dp.callback_query_handler(text="next")
async def photo_update(query: types.CallbackQuery):
    file_path = poster[2]
    reply_markup = neBTN
    file = InputMedia(media=file_path, caption="Updated caption :)")

    await query.message.edit_media(file, reply_markup=reply_markup)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого необходимо использовать пагинацию, подобное делал при помощи aiogram_dialog